# Debug on real device using android studio

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

When I run activities AndroidStudio recognize my phone(state:online, compatible:yes)  but on my phone nothing happens, the activity it's not installed.
Session *exampleActivity*: launched on samsung... but nothing on my phone.
Developer options is already activated on my phone.
I downloaded google usb driver from sdk tools.
Emulator works fine.
I got cm11 which runs kitkat 4.4.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you check in Run/Debug configurations ? Check in group "Target device" click to "Show chooser dialog" then uncheck "use same device..."

Comment: I just solved this, the problem was that I didnt make the activity launcher

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

1 - Close Android Studio and any other IDE you have opened (maybe you have Eclipse also running?) and emulator instances;

2 - Remove USB cable from PC;

3 - Run adb kill-server from console;

4 - Open Android Studio;

5 - Click on run/debug;

6 - When the window to select the device appears, attach your device to USB and USB to your computer;

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this, the problem was that I didnt make the activity launcher – Kenny Altamirano Barba